# jqplot highlights per bar

Tags: jqplot

I have bar chart and the following code for that:

```
 var line1=[['0-1',275134],['2-3',261562],['4-5',285681],['6-7',915432],['8-9',555131]];
 var line2=[['0-1',353628],['2-3',287898],['4-5',297550],['6-7',103313],['8-9',616089]];
 jQuery.jqplot('_container', [line1, line2], 
 {
    title: 'title',
    seriesColors: [ "#eee", "#ccc"],
    seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:jQuery.jqplot.BarRenderer, 
            rendererOptions:{barPadding:5, barMargin:5,highlightColors: ["#000", "#FF1100"]},
            pointLabels: {show: false}
    },
    legend:{
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
        show:true,
        showLabels: true,
        labels: ["Label 1", "Label 2"],
            rendererOptions:{numberColumns:2},
            placement:'outsideGrid',location:"s"
    },
    axes:{
        xaxis:{renderer:jQuery.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer, rendererOptions:{showDataLabels: false},showTicks: false},
        yaxis:{tickOptions: {showGridline: true}}
    },
    highlighter: {
        tooltipAxes: 'y',
        formatString:'%s'
    },
    cursor:{style:'default', show: true, zoom:true, showTooltip:false}
 });
```

How to add highlighting for bars by way as seriesColors works, so added highlightColors works by another way it's highlight first four bars ("#000", "#000","#FF1100","#FF1100"), but needed result is like ("#000","#FF1100","#000","#FF1100","#000","#FF1100", ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you experienced here was caused by a bug in the `barRenderer.js` and the only way to fix it seems to be edit of the appropriate line of its code[, as explained here.](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/413/wrong-bar-highlight-colors)

The required change involves replacing of `pidx` with `sidx` in the line:

`var opts = {fillStyle: s.highlightColors[pidx]};`

To verify it, I made [a jsfiddle where you can quickly see that it fixes](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/2mCjW/) the problem.